# Can I use sweet potato leaves as a dynamic accumulator?

Tags: fertilizer, organic

I have been thinking about growing Comfrey in my garden but I came across several articles mentioning that once it is in your garden, it is there forever because if you cut the roots, it grows like a earthworm, doubling itself.

I have Sweet Potato growing throughout my garden and I think it has a similar property with the roots. When I dig it up, it just comes back again, and grows throughout most of the year.

I found a list of dynamic accumulators that can be turned into compost.

http://oregonbd.org/Class/accum.htm

Is there any reason why legumes such as a sweet potato aren't listed? Where they listed on some websites, they are only considered Nitrogen sources. I'm not sure whether the root length is considered when categorising plants as dyanmic accumulators. Clovers don't appear to have a deep root system but are also dynamic accumulators. Could it be that "Dynamic Accumulators" are only weeds by definition?

Here is a nutritional factsheet for Sweet Potato leaves.
http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/vegetables-and-vegetable-products/2664/2
Apparently it is high in Calcium, Iron, Magnesium, Phosphorus, Potassium, and Manganese. This is similar to the Comfrey's nutritional content. So, would it be advisable to use this rather than planting Comfrey which I don't believe I would use other than for creating an organic fertiliser?

Some other weeds in my garden are Grass, Lemon Balm, Dandelions and Clover, but only the Dandelions would decompose to a rich compost high in trace elements and there aren't many of those growing in my garden.

I also have Biden pilosa growing in my garden because of my neighbour, but I noticed that if I use it in my compost, it just grows faster, so I just place it in the bin.

Answer (score 4):

No, it wouldn't be the same, Sweet potato simply isn't a dynamic accumulator. That doesn't mean you can't grow it, its a useful crop plant, and then add the plants to your compost heap, you can, any nutrients they contain will be useful, but won't be the same as, say, comfrey.

What's said about comfrey being a life long companion is sort of true - I've found, if you watch the patch during the year, and remove the offset plants in spring when they arrive, at that stage, you can easily dig them out if you go down a spade's depth, and the same in autumn if more have appeared. Once they take hold after a year, then its practically impossible to get them out, so what I'm saying is it's possible to have a comfrey patch that does not get out of hand IF you are vigilant and rigorous.